# Visualize random numbers generate

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

how can I visualize the random number which is generated in python without the help of any internal or external library of python?

This is the code I am trying with

```
def random(x,y):
  from time import time
  r = time() - float(str(time()).split('.')[0])
  random = r*(x-y)+y
  return random
random(23,53)
```

Comment: why the `numpy` tag? What exactly means "visualize"?

Comment: *"without the help of any internal or external library of python"* well, you are already using `time`, so...

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to write a random number generator from scratch?

Comment: yes from from scratch and plot the generated point

Comment: @irshadbaruah do you want to rewrite a known alogrithm, assuming the one numpy uses as you tagged it?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. you can use a density plot using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html),feeding in an array of your created random numbers.